# How do I replace characters in lists using dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, replace, key

I want to write a code that will replace certain characters in a list in an efficient way using a dictionary.

If I have:

```
key = {'a':'z','b':'y','c':'x'}
List = ['a','b','c']
```

How can I get the output

> zyx

edit to clarify. The output I want is really

randomvariableorsomething = ['z', 'y', 'x']
My apologies.

Will [key[x] for x in List] work if I don't have a key for it in the dict?

Comment: Please clarify: Your output seems to be a string. What do you mean by 'replace' in this case?

Comment: What should happen for an entry in the list with no corresponding key in the dict?  `['a', 'b', 'w']`?

Comment: Edited for clarity. Sorry, I have to get used to specifying stuff in questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `get` and `join`:

```
>>> ''.join(key.get(e,'') for e in List)
'zyx'
```

If by 'replace' you mean to change the list to the values of the dict in the order of the elements of the original list, you can do:

```
>>> List[:]=[key.get(e,'') for e in List]
>>> List
['z', 'y', 'x']
```

Comment: I was about to answer with `key.get(e, e)`, so I suppose we should nail down what the asker wants in the case of a key that isn't in the dict.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I edited the vague question to be more accurate. Output = ['z','y','x']

Answer (score 1):

```
key = {'a':'z','b':'y','c':'x'}
List = ['a','b','c']

print([key.get(x,"No_key") for x in List])

#### Output ####

['z', 'y', 'x']
```

If your interest is only to print them as string,then:

```
print(*[key.get(x,"No_key") for x in List],sep="")

#### Output ####

zxy
```

Just in case you need the solution without join.

```
ss = ''
def fun_str(x):
    global ss
    ss = ss + x
    return(ss)
print([fun_str(x) for x in List][-1])

#### Output ####

zxy
```

Comment: Apparaently not what OP wanted (`['z', 'y', 'x']` is not `zyx`), and the core of the solution is the same as the accepted answer. So, what is this good for?

Comment: He has clearly mentioned as output to be in a list. And taking your comment as, feedback have edited code a bit maybe that helps.

Comment: You're right. The statement "the output I want is really" comes only after the highlighted _How can I get the output zyx_. Anyway, you solution is not really new - and FYI it was flagged as "low quality post". Now it is much better, I think.

Answer (score -1):

Both keys and List are words in python that can collide with existing objects or methods (`dict.keys()` and `List` objects), so I replaced them with k and lst respectively for best practice:

```
[k[x] for x in lst]
```

Comment: Neither of those identifiers shadows an existing identifier, nor are they keywords.  `keys` is a method name of some classes, and `typing.List` exists, but neither of those effect this at all.

Comment: You're correct, I misspoke. Edited for clarity, thanks